# Nature of the minyan for reading Zachor

Tags: torah-reading, minyan, parshat-zachor

According to some opinions (see [Shulchan Aruch OC 146:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.146.2) and [685:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.675.7); and others), one is obligated to hear parashat Zachor read among a minyan, but one can (and must) read it without a minyan if there is no minyan. (I am not interested in discussing the nature of this obligation, or whether the minyan is obligatory or preferable.)

I am interested in the question of gathering a minyan in order to have a second reading of Zachor (for those who may have missed the first one). Assume that at least 10 men have gathered (who have not already heard Zachor), and there is thus reason to take out the Torah and read it (see for example [Mishnah Berurah 685:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.685.7?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=bi)).

Although I have seen the gathering of at least 10 men for such a reading, I have never observed other minyan-related activities (such as brachot or kaddish). Perhaps "reading in a minyan" mentioned in the halachic codes is simply code for "reading in the usual ritual spot"?

So, reading Zachor for/in the presence of such a crowd: **(a)** Is there any fulfillment of the minyan requirement/preference mentioned above, or is this simply a collection of individuals hearing Zachor? **(b)** If yes for (a), is there a requirement to say a bracha before and after on the reading, or kaddish after? **(c)** If yes for (a) (and no for (b)), is there anything needed to establish the minyan, or is the presence (and presumed attention) of the minyan sufficient?

---

Some of my thoughts not already mentioned: for **(a)**, perhaps there is no room for "public ritual readings" that come with the other practices outside the established times; but perhaps "reading in a minyan" is simply among 10. For **(b)**, we normally say brachot on public Torah readings, but this is outside the established time. We normally allow our morning Torah brachot to cover non-ritual Torah learning. Anecdotally, I've never seen a second reading done with a bracha. But perhaps since this is a reading of something required, we would say the brachot regardless. I saw in Minchat Yitzhak 9:68, that R. Weiss was asked about saying brachot at readings specifically for women, and he said not to because they may not be obligated, implying that for men one would say brachot. The answers to [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51262/) might imply that brachot should (or must) be said amongst a minyan, but that may only be talking about delayed "full Torah readings", not just reading "one aliyah-worth". For **(c)**, I recall something (somewhere) about the public recitation of Bar'chu or Kaddish at the beginning of public prayer establishing a minyan, so here too something might be required.

Comment: Good question. There were indeed Acharonim who argued for saying blessings, similar to a community that didn't have a Torah Shabbat morning and is reading the weekly Parsha at Mincha. Safek Brakhot leHakel is the (near?) universal practice, and indeed some discourage reading for women since why enter Safek Brakhot if they aren't obligated? Kaddish is an excellent point and indeed this should be no different from random communal Tehillim and get a Kaddish Yatom.

Comment: @DoubleAA If you recall specifics, could you please point me to some Acharonim who discuss this?

Comment: כתב הט"ז (סי' תרפה ס"ק ב) וז"ל: "ולענ"ד נראה דבקטן שאין יודע למי מברכין אין יוצאין ידי הברכה על ידו, ואין יוצאין ידי קריאה בלא ברכה, על כן אין להקרות למפטיר לקטן שאינו יודע למי מברכין". ולמדנו מכאן, שכדי לצאת ידי חובת קריאת פרשת זכור, חייבים לברך ברכות לפניה ואחריה, ואם לא בירך לא יוצא ידי חובת מצות קריאה. ולכן קטן אינו עולה לתורה לקריאת פרשת זכור, מכיון שהוא אינו יכול להוציא את הציבור ידי חובה בברכות.

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99:%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%9B%D7%90_-_%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_(Zvi_Ryzman) see there more about it

Comment: [Meiri on Brachot 1:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Meiri_on_Berakhot.11b.5) writes that any Torah reading יתר מכדי תקנת עזרא requires a bracha, just like tefillin require a bracha any time you put them on. Although he may just be discussing the aliyot after the first 3, the comparison to tefillin (which applies all day) suggests a broader application.

Answer (score 1):

If six of the ten men have not yet heard Zachor they certainly must say berachos. This is no different that on a Monday or Thursday when some people come to shul only for mincha (such as when they were traveling) where they read then with berachos and Kaddish. (I've done this several times.)

(I don't have any one source for this, but put it together from the following sources: Torah reading in the afternoon, MB 135:1. Only six who have not yet heared Torah reading, BH 143 s.v. ubipachos. Reading of Zachor separate from the main Torah reading, MB 685:2. He says there to say Kaddish afterwards.)

If less than six men have not heard Zachor, then the minhag, AFAICT, is not to say berachos. There is a Torat Rephael (siman 2) who says that any Torah reading before ten men must always have a beracha. But the latter poskim (for example Minchas Yitzchak mentioned in the OP) make distinctions.

I suggest that there is a difference between ten people who come as individuals, and ten who come together to make themselves into a congregation. But that would make it that a beracha would be said in this case where the ten are there so that there will be a minyan at the reading.

Comment: Is it really no different? Can you have a maftir separate from a main reading? Can you have a Torah reading separate from a Tefillah? Can you read a Shacharit reading at a Mincha that has its own Mincha reading?

Comment: You recited a kaddish after leining at Mincha? I've never seen that

Comment: Regarding your comment about reading a shachrisc reading by mincha - I've seen when Chu"l and E"Y are reading different parshiyos, those who need to catch up (bnei chu"l in E"Y or vice versa) will read the morning parsha at mincha as an add on to shlishi.

Comment: @Chatzkel that's subject to a machlokes; since there's no extra brachot in your case it doesn't hurt to be strict since really there's no need to catch up when moving to a location with a different leining practice. I didn't say no one could hold the OPs position, but it's not trivial