# Parshas Zachor when one can't get a Minyan?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, parshat-zachor

If one is staying away from large gatherings for medical reasons (eg. due to the risk posed by COVID-19) or if one's shul is closed (perhaps for the same reason), how might one satisfy the requirement (based on Devarim 25) to hear Parshas Zachor before Purim?  Read it oneself, from a chumash?  Silently or out loud?  Other?

Comment: I think that some of the talk around here recommended a reading on Purim instead of shabbos, and that megillah might be acceptable via phone, so one wonders if Zachor could also be possible by phone.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100795/nature-of-the-minyan-for-reading-zachor

Answer (score 8):

The Rama 685:7 writes that one should still read it with its correct tune.

הגה: ואם אי אפשר להם לבוא, מכל מקום יזהרו לקרותם בנגינתם ובטעמם (מצא כתוב).

The Kaf Hachaim 685:35 writes one should read from Sefer Torah preferably(without bracha),but if one doesn't have ,a chumash should be used.

לה) שם הגה. ואם א"א להם לבא מ"מ יזהרו לקרותם וכו' ר"ל אם יש להם יקראו אותם בס"ת אלא בלא ברכה כגין שאין מנין ואם אין להם ס"ת יקראו אותם בחומש של דפוס:

Comment: wow this is still relevant lol, is there a concept to read iton purim from a sayfoyr toyruh also?

Comment: tzuf dvash 169 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=507&st=&pgnum=24 quotes (and disagrees with) someone who allowed reading from a chumash with a minyan during some sort of shul-quarantine.