# Can the order of service on a fast day mincha be altered where circumstances demand?

Tags: fast-days, torah-service, mincha-afternoon-prayer, sunset-shekia

A minyan for mincha on a fast-day cannot get access to the sefer torah. If they wait, they may end up saying the mincha amida after shkia.

Q1: What halachic considerations are involved in saying the amida before reading from the Torah?

Q2: What halachic considerations are involved in reading from the Torah after shkia?

Q3: If one (amida or kri'as haTorah) has to be after shkia, does the halacha express a preference?

We have posed the questions to the LOR.

Comment: Note the answer may be say Amida now and skip the Torah reading completely. (You don't seem to consider that option.)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/krias-hatorah-or-megillah-before-davening

Answer (score -1):

Partial answer as it deals with the idea of reading the Torah after all prayers have been completed. I am uncertain what occurs if you can open the ark and read after the amidah. Though, it seems that you could. After all, that's what we do during Shacharit.

I am excerpting [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37977/5275) from another MY question. Kudos to @Yoni.

> The mitzvah of reading from the Torah on Shabbos, YomTov and Mondays
> and Thursdays takes place during tefillah but is not dependent upon
> it. Certainly the preferable mode of reading from the Torah is during
> davening but the mitzvah lasts all day and when a minyan is available
> they should read from Torah. (Mishne Berurah 135:1, Shaar Hatziyun 3
> and Aruch Hashulchan 135:6,7, Dagul Mervavah, Mahari Asad 58. However,
> some maintain that if mincha time has arrived, the Torah should not be
> read. See Mikraei Kodesh (Grodzinsky), Klal 13:5 and Shaarei Kedusha
> 10,11)

I can't imagine that the rules of the fast day reading would differ from what was mentioned above. So, as long as it is still before sunset, it seems that you can still read the Torah by itself even if you have completed *mincha*.

I'm not sure what happens if you have past sunset, as it is the next "day", perhaps.

Comment: היכי דמי? If it's not yet about to be _shkia_, why not just wait a bit and read the Torah first? If it is about to be _shkia_, this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: @Daniel That's correct. Though, strange as this may sound, sometimes, you have inpatient people who can't wait around. What can then happen is that you don't have a minyan, so that's worse.

Comment: that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @Daniel Yes. I've mentioned that as a comment on your comment, not the question. Seems obvious that if my scenario would happen then you would have to daven right away to keep your minyan.

Comment: So this answer does't address the question then. You have only attempted to address Q1 but you changed the scenario to be a different one from what the question is asking about.